# Removing adjacent values from vector

Tags: loops, vector, rust, infinite-loop

I made this function which should remove all adjacent values it finds from a vector.

```rust
fn remove_adjacent<T: std::cmp::PartialEq>(values: &mut Vec<T>, item: T) {
    let mut offset = 0;

    while let Some(idx) = values.iter().skip(offset).position(|n| *n == item) {
        let length = values
            .iter()
            .skip(idx)
            .position(|v| *v != item)
            .unwrap_or(values.len() - idx);

        if length > 1 {
            values.drain(idx + 1..length + idx);
        }

        offset = idx + 1;
    }
}
```

It works fine for vectors like

```rust
vec![2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
```

But not for vectors whose target element to be removed repeats after a non-target value, like

```rust
vec![2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 3];
```

It should also remove the threes `3` values after `7`, but instead it get stuck in an infinite loop. I'm not able find the error on my own, if anyone has tips on how to fix this I'll really appreciate it.

[**Example on Rust Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2293d8ef1a1c5013395b8bd12b3ee3fa)

Comment: Btw you can solve this using `dedup_by`: the whole function body becomes: `values.dedup_by(|a, b| a == &item && a == b)`. (I haven't looked in detail what the error in your code is.)

Comment: Usually when you write a more complicated function and it doesn't do what you expect it is useful to get a paper and pen and write down what it is actually doing step by step. Or use a debugger..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in your code works correctly except getting the `idx`.

You can print out the `idx` and see what is wrong with it. Printing `offset` helps too.

```rust
fn remove_adjacent<T: std::cmp::PartialEq>(values: &mut Vec<T>, item: T) {
    let mut offset = 0;

    while let Some(idx) = values.iter().skip(offset).position(|n| *n == item) {
        dbg!(idx, offset); // prints out nicely

        let length = values
            .iter()
            .skip(idx)
            .position(|v| *v != item)
            .unwrap_or(values.len() - idx);

        if length > 1 {
            values.drain(idx + 1..length + idx);
        }

        offset = idx + 1;
    }
}
```

**You will notice that the `idx` is not always what you want.**

This is happening becuase `.position(` counts not in `values` but in the iterator you get after `.skip(offset)`.

I hope looking at the printed values and my clue guides you to fix the error on your own. Good luck!